# Weekly boxplot from hourly data

Tags: r, ggplot2, zoo

I would like to create a weekly boxplot from data gathered hourly. It starts form 01-01-2014 till 11-10-2016.

```
Date       |Hour | Load
2014-01-01 | 1   | 15000
2014-01-01 | 2   | 15500
.......
2014-01-01 | 24  | 16000
2014-01-02 | 1   | 16500
.......
2016-10-11 | 24  | 20000
```

I know that it should be done with combination of zoo package and ggplot2 but I have no clue where to start.

It should look like these (without blue fill).
[image]

Comment: If your data column is a Date class then the simplest way is to create create a sequence of weeks and then use the cut function.  Such as: `scut<-seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2016-11-01"),by="1 week"); 
df$bins<-cut(df$data, scut)`.  In the future use the dput function to provide a sample of your dataset.

Comment: Thanks Dave2e. Yes, Date (sorry for mistake) column is a Date class. Does cut function collects information such as minimum, maximum, and median for each week?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329882/ggplot2-boxplots-by-week) seems closely related.

Comment: @aosmith Thanks :) This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @ppi0trek, to answer your question, if you are looking for min, max, etc for each grouping then take a look at the dplyr library and the group_by and summarize functions.

Comment: Is there an easy way to scale x axis? (right now I can see all numbers of weeks, instead  I would like to see only yearly scale).